# Different format for training and testing data

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification

How can I use different format of data for training and testing?

Currently I am working on a **classification problem** and the data format is different for training and testing. So, it is not able to classify properly. But my usecase is such that I have to use in that way only. Below is my format.

I have the following structure for training now:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| Attribute_Names   |  Attribute_Values        |   Category  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| Brand             |  Samsung, Nokia, OnePlus | Mobile      |
| RAM, Memory       | 2 GB, 4 GB, 3 GB, 6GB    | Mobile      |  
| Color,Colour      | Black, Golden, White     | Mobile      |   
--------------------------------------------------------------
| Fabric, Material  | Cloth, Synthetic, Silk   | Ethnic Wear |
| Pattern, Design   | Digital, floral print    | Ethnic Wear |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Testing**:  'Samsung Galaxy On Nxt 3 GB RAM 16 GB ROM Expandable Upto 256 GB 5.5 inch Full HD Display'

I have also posted this problem with explanation in data-science group:
[product-classification-in-e-commerce-using-attribute-keywords](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27468/product-classification-in-e-commerce-using-attribute-keywords)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: cross referencing questions is not a good practice. It splits the effort

Comment: First of all, if you really want help you need to give an actual example. What you posted does not really show the problem at hand, how should we help you when you don't even describe the problem accurately. In general, you mustn't change the data format, that invalidates the model. There are some special cases and workarounds but with the given information I can not help you (give us complete examples of training and testing rows, with description).

Comment: @meow : I know it is not a usual scenario but the example that I have provided is my actual use case. I have provided only 2 classes here and few attributes just for reference. But currently I have 39 classes and around 7000 attributes overall which could increase in future. The link that I have provided has detailed explanation.

Comment: @Sam so you are saying that you have no labels for the test data? I mean that kind of makes your problem an unsupervised one. I mean you know that you are testing to verify the models accuracy/ performance, which does not make any sense if you have no labels. In that case there are several approaches but what you are doing is definitely wrong (and I mean massively wrong if I understand you right).

Comment: @meow: I do have some initial data with appropriate labels to check whether the model is giving appropriate result or not on the basis of which I can check the correctness of the model.

Comment: So I'll try to give you an answer of how you could approach the problem, given that I understood it completely (which I'm not a 100% certain).

Answer (score 1):

As a very general **principle**, the format of the training & test data must be the same. There are not simple workarounds for this. There can be cases of course where the *information* contained in the attributes of the said datasets is essentially the same, only formatted differently; such cases are handled with appropriate data preprocessing.

If your data gathering process changes at some point in time, collecting different attributes, there are some choices available, highly dependent on the particular case: if you happen to collect *more* attributes that the ones with which you have trained your initial classifier, you can choose to simply ignore them, with the downside of possibly throwing away useful information. But if you happen to collect *less* attributes, there is not much you can do, other than possibly treat them as missing values in your prediction pipeline (provided that your classifier can indeed handle such missing values without significant decrease in performance); the other choice would be to re-train your classifier by dropping from your initial training set the attributes not collected in your new data gathering process.

Machine learning is not magic; on the contrary, it is subject to very real engineering constraints, the compatibility of the training and test data being one of the most fundamental ones. If you look around for real-world cases of deployed ML models, you'll see that the issue of possible periodic re-training of the deployed models pops up almost everywhere...

Comment: All the things mentioned are correct. But, is there any way I can process the data so that it gives appropriate results?

Comment: @Sam I already mentioned appropriate data preprocessing. Do you really expect a detailed answer (with code?) with only the meager information you have provided??

Comment: @Sam - this answer looks good to me. If the training set and real data are in a different format, I would manipulate the training set into the format of the live data (with unit tests, to ensure the translation didn't cause any errors). If it's just a case of additional attributes, I would follow the 'ignore' process also.

Comment: @HockeyJ  :Initially, I also thought of the same process to convert the training set into format of the live data by taking permutation and combination of attribute names and values, but it will make the data very huge.

Answer (score 0):

So based on your description I think what you have is a bunch of data, where some are labeled and most are not, which leaves you to a semi-supervised kind of setting.

Now, testing different data than what you trained is definitely a no-go. What you should do is mix-up the data so that you distribute your labels amongst both training and test set, that is if you wanna use a supervised methodology of course. Given that you did that you could use some techniques for label propagation, where you e.g. cluster similar data and assign the most frequent label inside that group, this can be as easy as a simple k-means clustering or as difficult as creating your own graph structure and implement a custom algorithm. So assuming you have fully labeled data now you can train your model on a mixture of real labels and assigned ones and test it **the same way**.
This is the only way you get a reliable performance evaluation. You obviously could also try to just train on the completely labeled data and evaluate on a mixture of real labels and assigned ones but I'd assume this would lead over-fitting.

Another related way would be to go create some kind of word vectors (google word2vec e.g.) and then use your labeled data as clusters (one per category) assign new unlabeled data to the most similar cluster (there are many variants and ways to do this).

There are many ways to tackle such a problem that are not some standard algorithms in a textbook but rather things you have to implement yourself or at least you need to do some serious preprocessing to make your data fit a standard algorithm.

I hope this helps a bit.